# Using exec family for a perl script

Tags: c

I try to execute a perl script from my C program using a exec family function.

The first try with execv give me an infinite loop, so i check the man page for execv and see that all this function call execve which is more suitable for what i want to do.

Giving up to know why I have an infinite loop (yeah, that's not clever, i know), I intend to use execve, but this one fail too with "No such file or directory".

So i check again the man page, see that

> [...]
>
> filename must be either a binary executable, or a script starting with a line of the form:
>
> #! interpreter [optional-arg]
>
> For details of the latter case, see "Interpreter scripts" below.
>
> [...]
>
> ENOENT
>
> The file filename or a script or ELF interpreter does not exist, or a
>   shared library needed for file or interpreter cannot be found.

So I write a code to check if both my perl scrip and the interpreter exist.

```
#define PERL_FILE "/home/path/script.pl"

int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *env[])
{
    FILE     *test;
    char     buffer[200];

    /* Test if PERL_FILE exist */
    if (!(test = fopen(PERL_FILE, "r"))) {
        fprintf(stderr, "main : fopen("PERL_FILE") : %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    /* Retrieve the beginning of the PERL_FILE file */
    if (fread(buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer), test) <= 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "main : fread : %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    fclose(test);

    /* I want to check if the file in the shebang exist */
    *strchr(buffer, '\r') = '\0';
    printf("shebang = |%s|\n", buffer + 2);
    if (!(test = fopen(buffer + 2, "r"))) {
        fprintf(stderr, "main : fopen(%s) : %s\n", buffer + 2, strerror(errno));
        return (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    fclose(test);

    char *argv2[] = {PERL_FILE, NULL};
    int i;

    for (i = 0; env[i]; ++i) {
        printf("%s\n", env[i]);
    }

    execve(PERL_FILE, argv2, env);
    perror ("And so ... ");
    return (EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Here the content of my perl script :

> #!/usr/bin/perl
>
> print "Hello world !\n";

and here the result of the code execution :

shebang = |/usr/bin/perl|

> [...]
>
> USER=root
>
> PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
>
> SHELL=/bin/bash
>
> [...]
>
> And so ... : No such file or directory

(I edited in order to clean my env).

So all this lead to my question : what I'm doing wrong ?
Can't I execute a Perl script with a exec function family ?

I added a space between the shebang and the interpreter (like "#! /usr/bin/perl") but that fail too.
I succed with "system", but i musn't use it.

Thank for your reading.

Comment: It looks like you have a carriage return character in your perl script (`'\r'`) after your shebang line. That is probably what is causing the error. You will need to use only a newline character (`'\n'`) after the shebang line in your perl script.

Comment: Hello,

Thanks, that was the problem ! Well, I don't really know why there is a carraige return, since this perl script was made on Debian, and I understand that the interpeter path wasn't |/usr/bin/perl| but |/usr/bin/perl\r|.

But this lead to an another bug : I don't retrieve "toto" in my stdout, and the man page doesn't say that stdout/stderr is redirected. I just got an empty result.

Comment: My bad ...

I use execve correctly (with a fork) and I get the expected result for the execution of the Perl script.

So the culprit was the return carriage, and the thing between the keyboard and the chair. 

Thanks ! Problem solve for me.
Have a good day :)